# Learning ASP.NET MVC with solid WPF/.NET background

Tags: .net, wpf, asp.net-mvc, silverlight, mvvm

I have a solid .NET background except ASP.NET MVC, which I'd like to pick up. In particular I've got a lot of experience with WPF (MVVM), various flavors of Silverlight, LINQ (POCO and XML) and of course the core framework (C#, VB and recently F# as well).

What I'm missing and could be relevant is (obviously besides ASP.NET MVC) LINQ to SQL and the Entity Framework.

I know the basics of "plain old" ASP .NET (but really not that much beyond the basics), but I'm no stranger to SQL, HTML, CSS, JS, etc.

**The question:** if you did learn ASP.NET MVC3 starting from a background similar to mine, what approach have you found to be the effective (or not) and thus would recommend?

**Note:** I should mention that I'm interested in best practices and patterns as well. I found out at my expense that this is maybe more important than learning "how stuff work" (for ex. almost every WPF book teaches you everything about templates, binding, etc. but don't mention MVVM or other patterns that are fundamental for a large project).

Comment: Nobody knows the best way you learn except for you.  Questions like this are impossible to answer.

Comment: You (and those that voted to close) are right, my mistake as the 'best' way is subjective. I've changed the question accordingly.

Comment: The question will be closed since no answers can be anything else than subjective. I would convert the question to a community wiki if I could.

Comment: Agreed, looks like a good candidate for community wiki.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tend to read the blogs of some of the developers on the ASP.NET MVC team as well as some other individuals that have good insight into the framework:

1. [Phil Haack](http://haacked.com/)
2. [Steve Sanderson](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/)
3. [Brad Wilson](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/)
4. [Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/)
5. [Scott Gu](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/default.aspx) (Normally does release announcements and introductions to new features)

Also, this [link](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/LinkRollupNewDocumentationAndTutorialsFromWebPlatformAndTools.aspx) post by Scott Hanselman has a bunch of ASP.NET MVC 3 links towards the middle that will help supplement the reading you can do at [www.asp.net/mvc](http://www.asp.net/mvc)

Answer (score 4):

The [asp.net mvc](http://www.asp.net/mvc) site is pretty good. Watch a few of the videos, read a couple of the tutorials, and then check out the sample apps which are full walkthroughs with source code available.

Comment: thanks, interesting link. Lots of resources there.

Comment: The ASP.NET MVC site is a great place to start. I have recommended it to many.

Comment: Accepted @amurra's answer, but this (and the other ones) are very good as well.

Answer (score 2):

Steve Sanderson's [book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/ASP-NET-Framework-Experts-Voice-NET/dp/1430228865/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1296222491&sr=8-1) is really good.

Comment: I would star with Sanderson's book. He covers ASP.NET very well and very pragmatic.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend this [channel 9 video](http://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/matthijs/aspnet-mvc-2-basics-introduction-by-scott-hanselman) from Scott Hanselman as a good place to start. It's called a Basic Introduction, but it doesn't go into *really* basic stuff.

It gives you a good overview of how MVC works, the "magic" behind it etc, and he explains why you might want to do some certain things.

He also gives a brief overview of why you might use MVC over webforms (traditional ASP.NET).

Answer (score 0):

The real power of MVC is when you start using it with patterns, etc. [dimecast.net](http://dimecasts.net/) has some great resource for after you have grasp the concept of asp.net mvc framework on a hold.